# How to stop the browser from resizing on mobile when the keyboard is opened, or the address bar disappears?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, viewport, viewport-units

When the address bar disappears on mobile or the keyboard opens, it affects the viewport size and therefore change any css values that use vh units.

Is there a way to make sure the vh and vw units retain their size even as the viewport itself changes?

Answer (score 1):

The answer will vary by browser.

On Safari and Chrome, the URL bar does not resize vh units (nor percentage based heights) unless they're used in position: fixed Elements. Unfortunately, Firefox does cause vh to resize with the URL bar even outside position: fixed and there's nothing you can do about it.

For keyboard, I believe Safari won't resize vh units either. Chrome and Firefox do. Again, there's no way to prevent vh units from resizing in this case.